# How to return only members if they exist with MDX

Tags: mdx

I'm new to MDX and need help.

I have a list of possible accounts I want to check in the database but not all of the accounts are actually members yet. So if I try to run the query it fails and tells me the member doesn't exist. Is there a way of error handling that I can make it ignore members that don't exist or another better way to setup the query to accomplish this?

Below basically what i've tried that gives the error

```
Select 
{[member].[Value]} on Columns, 
{[member].[Acount1],
[member].[Acount2],
[member].[Acount3],
...
[member].[Acount49],
[member].[Acount50]}
on Rows
```

For more clarification I'm looking for the SQL equivalent of

```
where account in ('Account1',Account2'...'Account50')
```

Comment: Will it be all members that currently exist, or a set definable with some sort of logic, rather than a list of 50 members?

Comment: your script will also fail as you have member dimension on more than one axis. But the original error you're getting maybe tricky to work around (upped as this is an interesting one)

Answer (score 0):

The following does not produce an error for me even though 20040101 is not a member in the cube:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    [Measures].[Sales Amount] ON 0
 ,{
    [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20040101]
   ,[Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20050101]
  } ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```